# flutter blank screen on desktop(windows)

Tags: flutter

Running my application on another Windows machine results in a blank window. I works fine on the development machine.

I have included all the dll-files + data folder + 3 extra dll files mentioned on the Flutter website.

I have also ran "dependencies" on the resulting .exe file and can't see any missing dll's.

Compiling the "mydemo" application works fine, so I assume there are some other external files my application needs.

I have tried looking through the output of "flutter run -v" to find any clues of extra files needed, but can't see anything useful.

What is the preferred way to tackle a problem like this? How can I find out what files/resources are missing to distribute my app? Is there a way to use the "debug" version on the other machine instead and bring out the debug console window? I would guess that would show me errors when the app tries to load the missing resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if any package you depend on has some additional file requirements: for example, I'm using `sqflite_common_ffi` in some of my projects, which needs an additional DLL file to run. I don't know what you're referring to 'dependencies' ran on the EXE, though.

In any case, when I can't get any good output or error from a project, I do this: open up Windows prompt, go to the directory where you have put all the required files, and run

```
your_exe_file >> logFile.txt 2>&1
```

which will output the standard output and the standard error to the file. The log file name and extension don't really matter, it will be a simple text file.
For example, if I dont put the additional DLL for `sqflite_common_ffi` in the same folder of the compiled EXE, the output of the command above will specifically mention the name of the DLL that is missing.

Comment: Awesome! That told me additional dll's where needed. Pretty crappy that Flutter does not include those automatically. It should be able to know this when compiling.

Comment: I don't know if they can, actually. Probably flutter could put the three "basic" ones in the build folder, but I won't bet on the external packages being able to do so, even the best written ones, let alone the others.

Answer (score 0):

if you got your project through a repository to run on another windows machine, use the command "flutter pub get"

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean? Of course I would need to run "flutter pub get" to get the dependencies before I build the .exe file, otherwise the app would not even build in the first place :)